# Python catching entry exception with decimal.InvalidOperation

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, decimal

I'm working an exception example copied from a book.

```
from decimal import *
entry=input("GRD Conversion")
try:
    grd_usd=Decimal(entry)
except decimal.InvalidOperation:
    print("Invalid: ",entry)
```

Instead of the expected error of Invalid: 3d for 3d as my entry I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/myuser/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC2018.1/scratches/scratch.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       grd_usd=Decimal(entry) decimal.InvalidOperation: []
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/myuser/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC2018.1/scratches/scratch.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       except decimal.InvalidOperation: NameError: name 'decimal' is not defined

I'm using Python 3.6 on a Mac.

Comment: since you did `from decimal import *`, change `decimal.InvalidOperation` to `InvalidOperation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, you have nothing named `decimal`. When using `from .. import *`, the package itself does not become a variable. Then it is impossible to find `decimal.InvalidOperation`

```
import decimal

entry = input("GRD Conversion")
try:
    grd_usd = decimal.Decimal(entry)
except decimal.InvalidOperation:
    print("Invalid: ", entry)
```